# How to mock a method with varargs and a thenAnswer lambda?

Tags: java, mockito, variadic-functions

I'm trying to mock a method that has a vararg in its signature. The original method:

```
public class ThisThing {
  public String doIt( Sumpin a, String b, String... c) {
    // return a string
  }
}
```

Here's my attempted mock (I read that `any()` matches a vararg):

```
when(mockThing.doIt(
    any(),
    any(),
    any()
  ))
.thenAnswer( (a, b, c) -> b );
```

But Eclipse is flagging `thenAnswer` as erroneous:

```
The method thenAnswer(Answer<?>) in the type OngoingStubbing<String> is not applicable for the arguments ((<no type> a, <no type> b, <no type> c) -> {})
```

But also the lambda expression as erroneous:

```
Lambda expression's signature does not match the signature of the functional interface method answer(InvocationOnMock)
```

I've also tried changing the second `any()` matcher to `anyString()` to no effect. Oddly, the errors all disappear if I replace the lambda with `a -> a`. Are multiple arguments not allowed in the lambda?

What am I doing wrong and can I do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Can you try `any(String[].class)`?

Comment: @RobSpoor, you mean for the third matcher? I just tried it and it has no effect.

Comment: That was what I was going for, but I wasn't sure it would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you problem is. You can mock a specific amount of method parameters and the mock will work

TestClass

```
@Mock
private SomeService someService;

@Test
void someTestMethodTest() {
  when(someService.testSomething(any(),any(),any(),any())).thenAnswer(new Answer<Object>() {
    @Override
    public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocationOnMock) throws Throwable {
        return "ooooo";
    }
  });
  String testsomething = someService.testsomething("a", "a", "a", "a");
  System.out.println(testsomething);
}
```

"actual implementation" in someService

```
public String testSomething(String a, String b , String... c){
  return "asad";
}
```

Are you sure that you want to work with "thenAnswer" and not with "thenReturn ? Working with return is usually easier.

**EDIT:**

When explicitly working with lambda is required the alternative would be

```
when(someService.testsomething(any(),any(),any(),any())).thenAnswer(a -> "oooo");
```

When explicitly getting inputparameter "2" as return the

```
when(someService.testsomething(any(),any(),any(),any())).thenAnswer(a -> a.getArguments()[1]);
```

will do the trick.

Comment: Is there any way to get `thenReturn` to return whatever is submitted as the second parameter as the response?

Comment: I have updated my answer. theReturn is easier to use since you only have to pass the return object. For your case of working with the input arguments the "thenAnswer" method is better because it offers more flexibility. Returning the second argument is possible with accessing the "invocationOnMock" like shown in my edit

Comment: Thanks for the edit! Did the trick!